# How to make smaller bubbels above bigger bubbels in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot, smaller bubbles will be hidden by bigger bubbles. if I use alpha, they will appear.  I would like that small bubbles superpose the bigger ones without using alpha

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(dplyr)
```

## The dataset is provided in the gapminder library

```
    library(gapminder)
    data <- gapminder %>% filter(year=="2007") %>% dplyr::select(-year)

    # Most basic bubble plot
   data %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, size=pop, color=continent)) +
geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small points are already plotted over the large points. What you need is an outline on the points. You can do this by selecting `shape = 21` and using the fill aesthetic for their overall color. Their outline can be whatever color you like, though here I have made them a darker version of the fill color, which gives a more subtle outline:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)
library(colorspace)

data <- gapminder %>% filter(year=="2007") %>% dplyr::select(-year)

data %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, fill = continent,
             color = after_scale(darken(fill, 0.3)))) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name = "Population (M)") +
  scale_x_continuous("GDP per Capita", labels = scales::dollar) +
  ylab("Life Expectancy") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  ggtitle("Average life expectancy 2007") +
  guides(size = "none",
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6))) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray95", color = NA),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 25, face = 2),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25, face = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: @Tpellirn see my update. You can change the various text labels with `theme`

Comment: @Tpellirn updated again. There are lots of great resources on this site for finding out how to change theme elements.

Comment: last thing i promise, I tried to change the title of the legend to continent percentage in two lines  I used  continent\ percentage and continent/percentage but did not work

Comment: To change the name on the legend, use the argument `name = "Continent/Percentage"` inside `scale_fill_brewer`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of @Allan Cameron's solution:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
  filter(year=="2007") %>%
  select(-year) %>% 
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, size=pop, fill=continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape=21, color="black") +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)", guide="none")+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, option="A") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  ylab("Life Expectancy") +
  xlab("Gdp per Capita")
```

[image]